# Gnome-terminal - vim colors not updating

Tags: terminal, vim, gnome, colors

[image: Sample Screenshot]

The above screenshot shows my problem. As I scroll down in vim, black lines start appearing. Please note that initially all is good, but the problem happens if I scroll down.

I've already tried searching for solutions, almost all the time I end up with gnome 256 color solution and vim t_Co, I've enabled both in the required configuration files already.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in `VTE`, the terminal emulation widget behind `GNOME Terminal` and many other terminal emulators. Version 0.44 introduced the breakage and 0.48.3 fixes it.

See [the details here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754596), or jump straight away to [the fix](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?id=a26a60b) if you feel like patching and recompiling a particular buggy `VTE` version. (After installing the patched version, you'll have to close all `GNOME Terminal` instances at once so that the server process restarts.)

Comment: would that cause problems like [this one in vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/1400)?

Comment: I don't think so, the screenshots look the other way around to be, buggy `VTE` would err on the side that is depicted there as the correct one. Please note that the linked bugreports mentions `iterm` and `Terminal.app` terminal emulators which have nothing to do with `VTE`. So even if it turns out to be buggy under `VTE` too, it's probably a bug in `vim-airline` rather than at least 3 different terminal emulators.

Comment: It is easily possible, though, that `vim-airline` looks buggy for the exact same core reason that made us change `VTE` (and unfortunately broke it in other ways, as seen above) at the first place, in version 0.44.

Comment: yeah i know it has been reported for different terminals then VTE mentioned here. However, notice that you in your answer explicitly mentioned that other terminals are affected also and second, I really doubt it is a airline bug, but rather a vim bug

Comment: Many thanks, I'm on 0.48.2, I guess I'll wait a little longer.

Comment: 0.48.3 has been released. I've updated the answer accordingly. If you're using a developer branch of a distro or a rolling release, you will probably get the update soon.